# Bootstrap carousel image size

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

Hi have a responsive problem in the sizing of a carousel images, 7 of them are in horizontal size (1800x1200) but one - the last - is in vertical and I can't code it propertly to have it responsive:

https://www.luismatera.art/refugio.html

Code for carousel is:

```html
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1 hidden-xs"></div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                
                <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="10000">
                  <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                      <img src="img/refugio/01.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                      <img src="img/refugio/02.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                      <img src="img/refugio/03.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    </div>                    
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                      <img src="img/refugio/04.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                      <img src="img/refugio/05.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                      <img src="img/refugio/06.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                      <img src="img/refugio/07.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                    </div>
     <div class="carousel-item" align="center">
                      <img src="img/refugio/08.jpg" class="d-block img-fluid" alt="...">
                    </div>  


                  </div>
                  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                  </a>
                  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                  </a>
                </div>

                    <p>Proyecto abierto</p>
                    <p align="right">Asturias · 2017/18</p>
                </div>

                 <div class="col-md-1 hidden-xs"></div>

        </div>
```

I have replaced **class="d-block w-100**" with **class="d-block img-fluid"**

Any help will be appreciated :-)

Thanks in advance,
Luis

Answer (score 2):

```
.carousel-fade .carousel-item, .carousel-item img  {
  max-height: 90vh;
}
```

fixes it. It simply sets the `max-height` of any `.carousel-item` to maximum 90% of viewport height, which seems to be what you're after.

Obviously, you can tweak it to whatever makes sense for your project (maybe `85vh`?).

Comment: Thanks, Andrei. I have tried your solution, but it doesn't work :-/   https://imgur.com/a/RqTWUWd

Comment: not working bro, i think change your answer into `.carousel-fade .carousel-item img`  {} should work ?

Comment: I see what you mean. I didn't notice it's cropping the image. You need to apply the same `max-height` to the image: `.carousel-item > img { max-height: 90vh}` Updated the answer. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks again, Andrei. I think it works. I have change the code to: <div class="carousel-item" align="center"><img src="img/refugio/08.jpg" class="d-block" alt="..."></div> without w-100

Comment: Yep. That pesky `w-100` has no business there. I personally think Bootstrap got it all wrong when they decided to use `!important`s for everything. Working with it was so much easier in previous versions.