# Bootstrap carousel images and sizes

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to show a responsive carousel. I have in the slideshow horizontal and vertical images (H size: 1400 x 935. V size: 624 x 935).

Problem appears in this project: https://www.luismatera.art/las-matas-via-muerta-i.html

The main problem is that text goes up and down each time the slide changes to horizontal to vertical.

I have this css code (provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54407116/bootstrap-carousel-image-size)):

```
.carousel-fade .carousel-item, .carousel-item img {max-height: 90vh;}
```

and this in src image:

```
class="d-block img-fluid"
```

But it doesn't work properly

Could anybody help me to keep the text always in the same position? (like [this](https://www.luismatera.art/encelado.html))

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The images vary in height, so try to also add a `min-height` that way there's some consistency when changing images:

```
.carousel-fade .carousel-item, .carousel-item img {
   max-height: 90vh;
   min-height: 90vh;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Cesar. I have try but it doesn't work correctly, horizontal images have lost it's proportion.